# Qtip on input focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, qtip

I want to show Qtip when input get focus. Here is my code:

```
<script>
    function inputQtip(){
    alert("Test");
    $('#aerobot[title]').qtip({
        position: {
            my: 'right center',
            at: 'left center',
            target: $('.aerobot'),
        },
        show: {
            when: {
                target: $('#aerobot'),
                event: 'focus',
            },
        }
    });
}
inputQtip();
</script>
```

And its not working. Alert popups. So function is executing. What is wrong with this qtip ? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's nothing wrong with this code. you just forgot to wrap it in document.ready function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    inputQtip();
});
```

Comment: Thank's. Now my talisman can speak with users, but only when move mouse on input field. But if people click TAB new qtip is not working...